# How to set start page in dotnet core web api?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, .net-core

I try to build a web application with dotnet core web api,but i do not know how to set index.html as start page which can be done with dotnet framework web api easily. And i tried to use `app.UseDefaultFiles();app.UseStaticFiles();` to solve this problem, however, it did not work.

Comment: Where is the index.html? In wwwroot folder or project root directory?

Comment: @ademcaglin wwwroot.i solved this problem by typing the right url in the browser.when i start the application,the browser will start with a url like ip:portnumber/api/values and i ignored it.just app.UseDefaultFiles();app.UseStaticFiles(); is ok.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

If you are using a static file as the default page, the following code can help you.

```
 app.UseDefaultFiles(new DefaultFilesOptions { DefaultFileNames = new 
     List<string> { "index.html" } });
```

If you are using the MVC view, just add the routing role.

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
   {
       routes.MapRoute(
           name: "default",
           template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");
   });
```

Comment: This needs to be done in Startup.cs => Configure() method.

Comment: I tried using MapRoute as suggested above, but it had no effect. I tried @Floris answer and worked, but not in the way I need it to: it actually redirects you to a different URL rather than making "mysite.com/page1" == "mysite.com", which is what I would expect MapRoute to do.

Comment: @demonicdaron, if you want a static file as start page, you need put file into wwwroot directory, for example, if I want set index.html as start page, just put index.html into wwwroot and add code as above mentioned.  If you want a set a controller as start page, just modify routing template.

Comment: I have several subfolders under Pages/ and want the site to default to one of those folders' index page, without moving that index page out of its folder. Is this possible at all? Or must I move the default page out of its folder and into the wwwroot folder at all costs?

Comment: seems you are using asp.net core 2.1 web application, and use new style of cshtml view, just add folder in Pages, and rename cshtml file as Index in the forder.  by the way app.UseDefaultFiles seems not work in this style mvc project.

Answer (score 122):

In `Properties/launchSettings.json` you can define the `launchUrl`

```json
"profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
        "commandName": "IISExpress",
        "launchBrowser": true,
        "launchUrl": "<your relative URL here>",
        "environmentVariables": {
            "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked, but not in the way I need it to: it actually redirects you to a different URL rather than making "mysite.com/page1" == "mysite.com". So when you browse "mysite.com", you are redirected to "mysite.com/page1". What I want is to display page1 to the user but still show "mysite.com" on their browser.

Comment: Hey @demonicdaron, Sounds like you need Attribute Routing. See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.1#attribute-routing

Comment: I Suggest adding: launchSettings.json can be found in the Properties folder.

Comment: nice and simple answer! +1

Answer (score 67):

**Step 1**

```
app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

**Step 2**

Create a folder called "wwwroot". put a file called index.html

**Step 3 (optional)**

If you are the using the auto generated template, you can remove make the launchUrl blank like this

```
"launchUrl": "",
```

Otherwise, you will have to manually keep going to the landing page every time during localhost running.

This is the correct way. But always use `UseDefaultFiles()` before `UseStaticFiles`
Otherwise it won't work.

For reference: [Core fundamentals of Static Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files)

Comment: These 2 lines combined with having the index.html file the wwwroot folder worked like a charm.

Comment: Will this work the same for Razor pages? I've got it to work with a .html page, but when I try with a .cshtml page, it doesn't load it.

Answer (score 21):

For Asp.Net Core 2.0/2.1/2.2 just right click on Project → Properties → Debug 
and next to Launch Browser checkbox set path to the startup page you want.

Comment: This was set to the default API on project creation in Visual Studio, which meant none of the other solutions mentioned worked but this did, thanks!

Answer (score 15):

Your index.html file must be in the wwwroot folder

> **wwwroot** / index.html

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files

Comment: This question has an accepted answer since a year ago. Are you sure that your answer is relevant?

Comment: This is very helpful. I am using ASP.NET Core 3.1. I tried accepted answer and all above high voted answers, none worked. Those answers only work if the static file is in `wwwroot` folder. This answer is relevant to the question.

Comment: Basically what we need is `app.UseDefaultFiles();` and `app.UseStaticFiles();` as in @sebulbamalastare  answer and `index.html` file in the `wwwroot` folder.

Comment: My asp.net core 3.1 flutter index.html not accessible.   I added  DefaultFilesOptions options = new DefaultFilesOptions();  options.DefaultFileNames.Clear();
            options.DefaultFileNames.Add("Views/index.html");        app.UseDefaultFiles(options);           app.UseStaticFiles();  app.UseRouting(); and cleared launch browser url  - error no localhost page can't be found

Comment: I had to copy all my flutter web build files to wwwroot and then the javascript worked.

Answer (score 7):

You can set any file in any folder under the wwwroot as defaut file by using options.DefaultFileNames.Add in startup.cs .
 
For example to use myfile.html in wwwroot/folder1/folder2/ myfile.html, you will add this in Startup.cs
 
     options.DefaultFileNames.Clear();
            options.DefaultFileNames.Add("folder1/folder2/ myfile.html");
            app.UseDefaultFiles(options);
            app.UseStaticFiles();

But some time it may not work. For example
I created project File menu > New > Project , then selected  .NET Core > ASP.NET Core Web Application and selected Web Api as project template.
F5 always open page api/values, even though I added index.html in wwwroot folder and added following in ***startup.cs***

```
DefaultFilesOptions options = new DefaultFilesOptions();
                options.DefaultFileNames.Clear();
                options.DefaultFileNames.Add("mypage.html");
                app.UseDefaultFiles(options);
               app.UseStaticFiles();
```

Then I ***opened project properties*** page and deleted the value in ***Debug/Launch browser box*** (which was set to api/values) 
Now setting of startup page is working and mypage.html is startup page. Note that this page should be in wwwroot folder as you have opted to use static files.

Comment: Clearing "api/values" from Project>Properties>Debug>Launch Browser did the trick for me.

Comment: I have tried adding  var defaultFileOptions = new DefaultFilesOptions(); 
 defaultFileOptions.DefaultFileNames.Add("../Pages/SomeFolder/Index.cshtml"); app.UseDefaultFiles(defaultFileOptions); but that did not work. I have several subfolders under Pages/ and want the site to default to one of those folders' index page, without moving that index page out of its folder.

Comment: "api/values" was not shown in Launch Browser box for me, but there was a line `"launchUrl": "weatherforecast"` which I had to remove from launchSettings.json (this is ASP.NET Core 3.1). It was a leftover from the project template that is created in this version. Static page showed up in development, but not in production. I just removed all instances of `launchUrl` and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

For dotnet core web api 3.1, on `launchSettings.json` file set `"launchUrl": "swagger/index.html",`

Answer (score 2):

For Asp.Net Core 2.2 right click on Project → Properties → Debug and next to Launch Browser checkbox set path to the startup page you want.

[Project VS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQvZ2.png)

Answer (score 0):

> net6，webapi

**This is my implementation code, I hope it can help you!**

### Step 1

file:Program.cs

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

### Step 2

newfile:wwwroot/index.html

```
Hello,World!
```

### Step 3

newfile:Controllers/HomeController.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace zgcwkj.Controllers
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Home
    /// </summary>
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// WebHost
        /// </summary>
        private IWebHostEnvironment _IWebHost { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Home
        /// </summary>
        public HomeController(IWebHostEnvironment iWebHost)
        {
            this._IWebHost = iWebHost;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Index
        /// </summary>
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var rootPath = _IWebHost.WebRootPath;
            var rootIndex = $"{rootPath}/index.html";
            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(rootIndex))
            {
                return View("No File");
            }
            var fileResult = PhysicalFile(rootIndex, "text/html; charset=UTF-8");
            return fileResult;
        }
    }
}
```

### Step 4

**run your webapi**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

If Index.html is in project root, it will be send by default.