# NET CORE - How to create Home Page in API?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

Everytime my api is started, it's executed with `LOCALHOST:PORT/api/values/`. How to `LOCALHOST:PORT/` with a static home page?

Comment: you mean how to load `LOCALHOST` by default or how to add content when you open `LOCALHOST`?

Comment: Can you elaborate? Does the LOCALHOST have a port following it? Where are you calling this endpoint from?

Answer (score 0):

In your project, locate your launchSettings.json file. In visual studio you will need to expand Properties to find it from solution explorer or use Ctrl + T. This file contains an array of profiles. Each profile has a launchUrl field where you can mention your path as empty.

As of adding a content in the home page, you can always make a middleware as follows:

```
app.Use(async (context, _next) => {

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Request.Path.ToString())
            || context.Request.Path.ToString() == "/")
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Web API is now running.");
    }
    else
        await _next();
});
```

You can always have an action, But I would recommend using a middleware like the above.

Comment: How to set html page?

Comment: look into this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files

Answer (score 0):

possible duplicate of [How to set start page in dotnet core web api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40646815/how-to-set-start-page-in-dotnet-core-web-api)

I assume you mean having a default page when the user navigates to http://localhost instead  of calling http://localhost/api/controller.

In .net core 2 it's fairy easy to do. You can use static files if you only want to show a simple static page by adding

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) 
{
    ...other code here... 
    app.UseDefaultFiles(new DefaultFilesOptions { DefaultFileNames = new List<string> { "index.html" } });
    app.UseDefaultFiles();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
 }
```

and making sure there is an index.html in the wwwroot folder.

or you could use routing in mvc

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
   {
       routes.MapRoute(
           name: "default",
           template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");
   });
```

see answer by aslan at https://stackoverflow.com/a/40651363/3786363

oh and unless your server is mapped to port 80 you will probably need to call localhost:port not just localhost.

Answer (score -1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
$.ajax({
   url: "/api/values/METHOD/?PARAM=0",
   type: "GET",
   dataType: "json",
   cache: false,
   statusCode: {
     200: function (data) {
        //Do stuff
     }
   }
});
```

Anything running within the solution context will start at the root.